# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.journal.ui.home.HomeViewModel

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragment

Estaba desarrollando una App en Android con Java, en la que implemento el Navigation Component,además de una BBDD con Firebase.

Todo estaba funcionando correctamente hasta que me he puesto a tocar uno de los fragment de la App y ha craseado.

Aqui el código:

HomeFragment.framgment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private TextView txtUser;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //TODO: Ver porque cojones no funciona ahora el puto fragment despues de enrredar con el ViewModel
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        txtUser = (TextView) txtUser.findViewById(R.id.txtUser);

        //TODO: Consulta a la BBDD de Firebase para averiguar el usuario conectado.
        //Recover the data of the users.
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(mAuth!=null){


            //TODO: Averiguar porque mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail() devuelve null.
            String user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            homeViewModel.setmText(new MutableLiveData<String>(user));
            txtUser.setText(user);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha encontrado ningun usuario registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

Si teneís idea de por donde van los tiros, gracias por adelantado!

[EDIT]

Añado la clase del ViewModel a la cual necesito pasarle el nombre de usuario que tenga Firebase registrado en la BBDD:

HomeViewmodel.java

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public void setmText(MutableLiveData<String> mText) {
        this.mText.setValue("BIENVENIDO A BIRD-LAND: " + mText);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega la clase HomeViewModel , el problema es seguramente es lo que comento en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando un `ViewModelProvider`

```
 private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
 ...
 ...
 homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
```

pero obtienes el error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ...
> ViewModel

debes asegurar que el constructor de la clase `ViewModel` tenga un constructor definido como  `public`.

Ejemplo:

```
public HomeViewModel() {

}
```

Comment: Claro, peromi problema esq necesito pasarle el nombre del usuario, que tenga firebase registrado en la BBDD al ViewModel, por lo que necesito que el ViewModel lo reciba como paremetro, pero si uso despues ese constructor me da un error por duplicidad al tener dos instancias sobre el mismo objeto

Comment: Si, el constructor es un ejemplo, agrega tu clase para darte una respuesta concreta. @ManuelLucas